# Can't embed tweets in Windows Phone 8.1 WebView

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, twitter, webview

I'm trying to embed tweets in my webview, but they only show up as text. I've tried using twitter's suggestion and adding this script to make it load:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s
[0],p=/http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

When using that same HTML on my desktop, tweet embedding works. I'm wondering if:

A) Anyone has successfully gotten this to work?

B) Do I have to enable some sort of JavaScript or ability to run scripts in the webview?

Note: I've seen that in Windows Phone 8.0, WebBrowser allowed you to set IsScriptEnabled to true; however, I have yet to see anything like that in the WebView in WP8.1.